# Parsing JSON and creating data-frame in analyzable format in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to analyze the deduplication data, which get stored in Json format in Database. I am using below-mentioned query to fetch the required details from Database and created a dataframe which appears to be as followed.

Query:

```
SELECT ID,Result,Remark,Json,Date 
FROM Table1 
WHERE DATE(Date)>='2019-01-01'
AND DATE(Date)<='2019-05-31';
```

Dataframe:

```
ID       Result       Remark       Json        Date
XTR-1     Pass         Matched      {Json}      2019-01-01 18:25:12
XTR-4     Failed       No Match     {Json}      2019-01-01 13:20:23
XTR-7     InProgress   Matched      {Json}      2019-02-01 15:23:10
```

The sample json file

```
{
  "title": [
    {
      "category": "Category A",
      "uniqueId": "XRT-1",
      "status": [
        {
          "field": "E1",
          "value": "xdrts",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category A",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "l.ce",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category B",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "u.vE1",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category C",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "Category Cs.E1",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "E2",
          "matchingApp": []
        },
        {
          "field": "E3",
          "value": "9191919191",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category A",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "l.cE2yM",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category C",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "C C.m",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Marc D",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "cb.E3s",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category B",
      "uniqueId": "b6ae",
      "status": [
        {
          "field": "E1",
          "value": "xdrts",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category B",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "u.vE1",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category A",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "l.ce",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category C",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "Category Cs.E1",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "E3",
          "value": "9191919191",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category B",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "u.uE3",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Ref",
      "uniqueId": "b18b",
      "status": [
        {
          "field": "E3",
          "value": "7800252426",
          "matchingApp": []
        },
        {
          "field": "E1",
          "matchingApp": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Ref",
      "uniqueId": "8698",
      "status": [
        {
          "field": "E3",
          "value": "1282",
          "matchingApp": []
        },
        {
          "field": "E1",
          "matchingApp": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "BeDet",
      "uniqueId": "707126",
      "status": [
        {
          "field": "E4",
          "value": "4519",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E4",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "E4s",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "xcdetails.accNumber",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Marc D",
      "uniqueId": "88d6",
      "status": [
        {
          "field": "E3",
          "value": "0552,9415,9125",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category A",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "l.cE2yM",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category C",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "C C.m",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Marc D",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "cb.E3s",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Marc D",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "cb.E3s",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "E2",
          "value": "AY2218Z",
          "matchingApp": []
        },
        {
          "field": "E1",
          "matchingApp": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category C",
      "uniqueId": "88d6",
      "status": [
        {
          "field": "E1",
          "value": "xdrts",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category A",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "l.ce",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category B",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "u.vE1",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E1",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category C",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "Category Cs.E1",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "E2",
          "value": "AY2218Z",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E2",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category C",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "Category Cs.E2Hash",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E2",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Marc D",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "cd.jsE2H",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "E3",
          "value": "9191919191",
          "matchingApp": [
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category A",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "l.cE2yM",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Category C",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "C C.m",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            },
            {
              "appId": "XRT-2",
              "field": "E3",
              "flag": false,
              "Id": "765djhf45",
              "category": "Marc D",
              "Name": "AFFH",
              "targetField": "cb.E3s",
              "lastUpdateDate": "Jul 29, 2019 5:04:56 AM",
              "as": "A R",
              "AART": "B C"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "restrictedIdentities": []
}
```

The Json File structure contains below-mentioned parameters.

The `Category` field in the json contains following category:

```
Category          field

Category A        E1,E2,E3
Category B        E1,E2,E3
Category C        E1,E2,E3
Marc D            E1,E2,E3
ref               E1,E2,E3
BeDet             E4
```

The each `Category` contains three `field` except for the category `BeDet` which contains only one `field` E4. Now I want to extract the information from JSON on month as well as date basis that against for each field how many matchings found for each field in a different category.

My expected output looks something like:

```
Jan-19                   E1                          E2                          E3                E4            Result
         T1     T2   C1   C2  C3  C4  C5     C1   C2  C3  C4  C5     C1   C2  C3  C4  C5           C6    Pass    Failed  InProgress   Total
Matched  1      1    1    1   0   0    0     0    1   1   1   0      0    0   0   0   0             1      1       0        0         1
No Match 0      0   0    0   0   0    0     0    0   0   0    0     0    0    0   0   0             0      0       0        0         1
Pending
```

Where,

1. `T1`: The total number of distinct `ID` in particular month ( i.e 2 in month of Jan-19)
2. `T2`: The total number of distinct `ID` match with different `ID` in JSON (i.e in sample json `XTR-1` match with `XTR-2` only, there are scenarios where one distinct `ID` could get matched with n number of `ID`s)
3. `E1` to `E4`: These are just abbreviation of field, suppose the value of `E1` match with `Category A` value then the count would come in `C1` column. A similar process goes on for different `field` and `Category`.
4. `Matched`/`No Match`: The aggregate count of Matched and No Match `ID` as per dataframe column `Remark` group by month
5. `Pass`/`Failed`/`InProgress`: The aggregate count of the same group by month in the output dataframe
6. `Total`: Total of `ID` group by `Remark`.

For the scenarios where there are no match for any particular field then the `matchingApp` variable in the JSON would be []

Note: `E1` to `E4` are proper text in the original JSON, I have denoted with sign here for the sake of simplicity. And, the count should be in sync with group by month, result and remark

For the another `Month` (i.e `Feb-19`), the same table append below the `Jan-19` table in the same order and so on

The `Result` and `Remarks` are static value and are more than what i have mentioned in the question, It should be hardcoded in the Code

Comment: It's not clear to me where you're running into an obstacle that you need help resolving. Are you having trouble extracting the JSON, or in munging and summarizing it? From the way it currently appears, it sounds more like a project you want someone to write for you than a coding question.

Comment: @JonSpring: Yes Jon, Its a kind of project while learning R. I tried a lot but couldn't parse the JSON in the requier format.